# How to resample the dataframe into seconds bin

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
    DateTime
0   2020-04-04 10:15:40
1   2020-04-04 10:15:56
2   2020-04-04 11:07:11
3   2020-04-04 11:08:14
4   2020-04-04 11:18:46
.    .
.    .
```

And I want to resample this dataframe into seconds bin (with a shorter range).

I tried: `dfd.resample('30S')[0:5]` where `dfd` is my datagram, but it gives me `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`.

I also converted `DateTime` to datetime type by doing `dfd['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfd['DateTime'])` but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put DateTime to index using `dfd.reset_index('DateTime', inplace=True)`. Here is a comment from the manual:

> "Convenience method for frequency conversion and resampling of time
>   series. Object must have a **datetime-like index** (DatetimeIndex,
>   PeriodIndex, or TimedeltaIndex), or pass datetime-like values to the
>   on or level keyword."